# Radio button label not showing properly

Tags: html, css

I have three radio buttons which I have set a label for each  of them. For some reason the labels seem to merge into my radio buttons.

How do I stop them from merging and give them better spacing?

Here's a fiddle of what I have tried

```css
#radios {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.input1 {
  margin-left: 12px;
}

input[type="radio"] {
  position: absolute;
  right: 1000%;
}

label {
  float: left;
  width: 4%;
  padding-bottom: 4%;
  margin: 0 2.5%;
  background: #0096ff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#slider {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0%;
  top: 0;
  width: 2%;
  padding-bottom: 2%;
  margin: 4px 0 0 14px;
  background: #000;
  transition: transform 1s;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-duration: .3s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  transition: 0.2s left .05s ease-in-out;
}

#input1:checked~#slider {
  animation-name: input1;
  left: 0;
}

#input2:checked~#slider {
  animation-name: input2;
  left: 9%;
}

#input3:checked~#slider {
  animation-name: input3;
  left: 18%;
}

#input4:checked~#slider {
  animation-name: input4;
  left: 27%;
}

#input5:checked~#slider {
  animation-name: input5;
  left: 36%;
}

@keyframes input1 {
  30%,
  70% {
    transform: scale(0.5);
  }
}

@keyframes input2 {
  30%,
  70% {
    transform: scale(0.5);
  }
}

@keyframes input3 {
  30%,
  70% {
    transform: scale(0.5);
  }
}

@keyframes input4 {
  30%,
  70% {
    transform: scale(0.5);
  }
}

@keyframes input5 {
  30%,
  70% {
    transform: scale(0.5);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="radios">
  <label class="input1" for="input1">aa</label>
  <input id="input1" name="radio" type="radio" />
  <label class="input1" for="input2">sss</label>
  <input id="input2" name="radio" type="radio" />
  <label class="input1" for="input3">dd</label>
  <input id="input3" name="radio" type="radio" />
  <span id="slider"></span>
</div>
```

Live view here https://jsfiddle.net/xh7ofaz9/1/
It should have  space between the labels

This is it should look like--> [image]

Comment: You want all the labels to run into each other? Don't understand your question

Comment: Add you code _within_ your question

Comment: @Keith [enter image description here][1] this is the expected output that i wnt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an approach to do this. Basically, you can't set the label's background itself because you need to separate the visual and the text.

In order to do so, I used the `:before` pseudo element and did some essential styles change. I must to admit, I don't like to set fixed width (`width: 16%;`) to elements but I can't see other option to do that animation without javascript.

The most similar approach I found is this: https://codepen.io/web-tiki/pen/JXwLGQ/ but it without label's text so it's easier..

```css
#radios {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.input1 {
  margin-left: 12px;
}

input[type="radio"] {
  position: absolute;
  right: 1000%;
}

label {
  float: left;
  width: 16%;
  margin: 0 2.5%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

label:before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #0096ff;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

#slider {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0%;
  top: 0;
  width: 2%;
  padding-bottom: 2%;
  margin: 4px 0 0 14px;
  background: #000;
  transition: transform 1s;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-duration: .3s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  transition: 0.2s left .05s ease-in-out;
}

#input1:checked~#slider {
  animation-name: input1;
  left: 0;
}

#input2:checked~#slider {
  animation-name: input2;
  left: 22%;
}

#input3:checked~#slider {
  animation-name: input3;
  left: 44%;
}

#input4:checked~#slider {
  animation-name: input4;
  left: 27%;
}

#input5:checked~#slider {
  animation-name: input5;
  left: 36%;
}

@keyframes input1 {
  30%,
  70% {
    transform: scale(0.5);
  }
}

@keyframes input2 {
  30%,
  70% {
    transform: scale(0.5);
  }
}

@keyframes input3 {
  30%,
  70% {
    transform: scale(0.5);
  }
}

@keyframes input4 {
  30%,
  70% {
    transform: scale(0.5);
  }
}

@keyframes input5 {
  30%,
  70% {
    transform: scale(0.5);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="radios">
  <label class="input1" for="input1">aa</label>
  <input id="input1" name="radio" type="radio" />
  <label class="input1" for="input2">sss</label>
  <input id="input2" name="radio" type="radio" />
  <label class="input1" for="input3">dd</label>
  <input id="input3" name="radio" type="radio" />
  <span id="slider"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Can we have space between "a" and Blue circle (radio button and its label)

Comment: Something like that?